# Loding old keras models in tensorflow2.x

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to load a model saved using TensorFlow 1.x in tensofrow 2.x.

When loading the old model using tensorflow.keras.models.load_model.
I get an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'to_float'
```

Anybody with a suggestion on how to solve :).

Comment: Which method you used to save TF1.x model? what format you saved "tf" format or "h5" format? Did you had any custom layers or custom_objects? Is this sequential/functional/subclassed model?

Answer (score 0):

While the origins of the error in question are not clear for me, I'd like to suggest a generic sketch for handling weird checkpoint situations. It should work in TensorFlow 2.1.

```py
checkpoint_filename = '/path/to/our/weird/checkpoint.ckpt'
model = tf.keras.Model( ... ) # TF2.0 Model to initialize with the above checkpoint

from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_utils import load_checkpoint, list_variables

reader = load_checkpoint(checkpoint_filename)
for w in model.weights:
    name=w.name.split(':')[0] # See (b/29227106)
    print(f"Loading {name}")
    w.assign(reader.get_tensor(
        # Variable renaming 
        {'/var_name1/in/model':'/var_name1/in/checkpoint',
         '/var_name2/in/model':'/var_name2/in/checkpoint',
         # ...  and so on
         }.get(name,name)))
```

Model varaibles should have matching names and shapes in general. In case of name mismatch, check the difference by comparing outputs of `model.weights` and `list_variables`, then update the renaming dictionary of the snippet. Note, that this method will not restore model's optimizer state.